# Passing arguments to a function which is called by another function by its name in R

Tags: r, function, arguments, function-call, forecast

I am using two functions, say `Fun1` and `Fun2`, both are defined in a package, so I cannot change them. `Fun1` is calling `Fun2` as follows:

```
Fun1(x=a_number,y=a_string,fn=Fun2,...)
```

where `...` are arguments used by `Fun2`.

So `Fun1` is calling `Fun2` by its name. How can I pass parameters to `Fun2` without calling parameters names explicitly?

Assume that `args` is a list of parameters that I want to pass to `Fun2`. If I want to call **only** `Fun2` it is easy as follows:

```
do.call(Fun2,args)
```

But this way does not work if `Fun2` is called by `Fun1` by its name. The only way is to write parameters explicitly as follows:

```
Fun1(x=a_number,y=a_string,fn=Fun2,param1=sth,param2=some_other_thing)
```

But this way doesn't work for me as there are so many parameters of `Fun2` (not just 2) and also I don't know which parameters a user wants to change. Maybe the user just wants to change param1, and keep others as default.

By the way, the following does not work since `Fun1` does not accept anything but name of function for its 'fn' argument:

```
Fun1(x=a_number,y=a_string,fn=do.call(Fun2,args))
```

EDIT 1:

`fn=Fun2 (...)` doesn't work, because " fn" argument of `Fun1` only gets name of the function, nothing else.

EDIT 2:

Actually `Fun1` is `baggedModel` and `Fun2` is `auto.arima`, both of them are in forecast package. Here is an example:

```
vec.ts=ts(1:27,start=c(2016,1),frequency=12) #time series
num_blocks=3
block_size=24
baggedModel(vec.ts,
         bootstrapped_series = bld.mbb.bootstrap(vec.ts,num_blocks,block_size),
         fn=auto.arima,...)
```

So, I am looking for a way to pass some arguments to `...` part which will be  used by `auto.arima` function, **without explicitly mentioning names of arguments**.

Comment: Does `Fun2(...)` not work?  If it doesn't you need to explain why not.

Comment: @MrFlick I cannot produce a reproducible example as I don't know how `Fun1` is calling `Fun2` by its name actually. Sorry. But I will add details of those functions.

Comment: @MrFlick just did. Thanks!

Comment: @MrFlick `auto.arima` has many arguments. For instance, sometimes I want to change `ic` argument, sometimes `stepwise` argument, and sometimes both. If I only call `auto.arima` , then `do.call(auto.arima, args)` works, where args is a list of arguments such that `args=list(ic="bic",stepwise=TRUE)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the inputs `fun1`, `x`, `fun2` and `args` shown below the last line runs fun1.

```
fun1 <- function(x, fn, ...) fn(x) + fn(...)
x <- 3:4
fun2 <- sum
args <- list(1, 2)


do.call("fun1", c(list(x, fun2), args))
## [1] 10
```

Comment: It is working! Thanks so much!
(It seems my first try is wrong)

Answer (score 1):

Using the simplified example from @GGrothendieck. You can also use `purrr` to create partials (functions with some parameters already filled)

```
library(purrr)
fun1 <- function(x, fn, ...) fn(x) + fn(...)

x <- 3:4
args <- list(1,2)
fun2 <- sum
fun3 <- partial(fun2, !!!args)

fun1(x, fun3)
```

Here we create `fun3` with is just like `fun` but with 1 and 2 already passed as parameters (we just splice the in, requires purrr >0.3).

With the `baggedModel` example, you can just pass in an anonymous function as well and not bother with the ellipsis

```
vec.ts=ts(1:27,start=c(2016,1),frequency=12) #time series
num_blocks=3
block_size=24
baggedModel(vec.ts,
    bootstrapped_series = bld.mbb.bootstrap(vec.ts, num_blocks, block_size),
    fn=function(...) auto.arima(..., d=NA, D=NA)) # or whatever params you want
```

`baggedModel` can accept any type of function, it doesn't have to be a literal named function.